# нужно изменить img src у одного из элементов класса

Tags: html, jquery

при клике на div должен появляться блок с текстом и меняться картинка, находящаяся в этом div'е. Таких div 3 штуки и у картинок внутри один и тот же класс, как сделать так, чтобы менялась только та картинка на родительский блок которой кликнули. имеется вот такой набросок jquery, текст выплывает а картинка не меняется:

```js
function diplay_hide(blockId) {
  if ($(blockId).css('display') == 'none') {
    $(blockId).animate({
      height: 'show'
    }, 500);
    $('this.arrow').attr("src", "images/up-arrow.png");
  } else {
    $(blockId).animate({
      height: 'hide'
    }, 500);

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="span left" onclick="diplay_hide('#hidden_block');return false;">
  <img src="images/photo.png" class="photo left" alt="">
  <p class="px14">PHOTOGRAPHY</p>
  <label class="right" for="toggle">
    <img src="images/down-arrow.png" class="arrow" alt="">
  </label>
  <div class="hidden-text px14 grey" id="hidden_block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работает с `this` находит классы только в блоке на каторый нажали.

```js
 function diplay_hide(blockId) {
  if ($(blockId).children('.hidden_block').css('display') == 'none') {
    $(blockId).children('.hidden_block').animate({
      height: 'show'
    }, 500);
    $(blockId).parent().find('.photo').css('display','block'); 
    $(blockId).children('.arrow').attr("src", "images/up-arrow.png");
  } else {
    $(blockId).children('.hidden_block').animate({
      height: 'hide'
    }, 500);
    $(blockId).parent().find('.photo').css('display','none'); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span left" onclick="diplay_hide(this);return false;">
      <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/289333/349563746/stock-photo-best-internet-concept-of-global-business-from-concepts-series-elements-of-this-image-furnished-by-349563746.jpg" class="photo left" alt="">
      <p class="px14">PHOTOGRAPHY</p>
      <label class="right" for="toggle">
        <img src="images/down-arrow.png" class="arrow" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="hidden_block hidden-text px14 grey">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: замените ему `id="hidden_block"` на `class`

Comment: заменил спасибо